# Sql Server 2005 Reporting service was disable during Installation on Windows 7 professional

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

For our project, we need sql server 2005 reporting service. When i tried to install sql server 2005 i can see reporting service but it was disabled .

I tried all setting given i web like enable some components In "Turn windows feature on/off"

1)Internet Information Services.

2)Open World Wide Web Services.

3)  Application Development Features.

4) ASP.NET

Since my system was 64bit, i executed this script too

cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 0

although still Reporting service was in disabled state

Pls help in this, do i need to do any other settings

I found sql server 2008 reporting service was working perfectly in my system, but our existing project module was configured such that its looking for some sql server 2005 reporting files on IIS

Comment: What edition of SQL Server 2005 are you installing? Reporting Services doesn't come with all editions.

Comment: Thanks ken ...It was SQLServer2005 -32 bit server, i can see the Reporting service option during installation but it was grayed out, so that i cant able to select that.. if that edition will not support means it will not display it as option right ?

Comment: That tells what **version**, but not what **edition** (for instance, Visual Studio has Express, Professional, Enterprise, and SQL Server has CE, Express, etc.). Not all editions contain the same features, and it might be greyed out because it's not available in the edition you're installing.

Comment: It's sql server 2005 Developers edition

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution finally,

Since i need to install 32 bit reporting service  on my system first we need to remove existing 64bit reporting service which installed in system.

"Uninstall any 64-bit report server instances that are on the same computer. On a 64-bit computer, you cannot run 64-bit and 32-bit instances of Reporting Services. If you have an existing 64-bit Reporting Services installation, run Setup to uninstall it."

Once completed

run this script

cscript %SystemDrive%\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1

Then go to IIS (ie inetmgr)

select ApplicationPool and selecte "SetDefaultApppoolDefaults" on right hand side and set 
"Enable32bitApplication as True"

Now u can see the Reporting service option during installation

I faced problem because already in my system sqlserver2008 reporting service was there since it was 64 bit i doest allow me to install 2005 32 bit reporting service

Thanks